# Can `nullopt` be passed as non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>

std::experimental::optional<int> dflt(42);

template<const std::experimental::optional<int>& Dflt>
void foo() {
    if (Dflt) {
        std::cout << "default is set" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "default is not set" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
        foo<dflt>();                       // <-- OK
        foo<std::experimental::nullopt>(); // <-- NOT OK
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to pass `nullopt` as a non-type function template parameter but it doesn't compile. It works with a global variable `dflt` with static storage though.

The compiler error message looks like this:

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cc:13:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo()’
  foo<std::experimental::nullopt>();
                                  ^
foo.cc:7:6: note: candidate: template<const std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<int>& Dflt> void foo()
 void foo() {
      ^
foo.cc:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cc:13:34: error: could not convert template argument ‘std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::nullopt’ to ‘const std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<int>&’
  foo<std::experimental::nullopt>();
```

I know the example is silly, but my main question is, can `nullopt` be passed as non-type template parameter at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Not the way you try to pass it.

The longer answer has to do with the constraints placed on template arguments. Your template parameter is of a reference type. The corresponding argument for it must fulfill the requirements in [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2) (emphasis mine):

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
>   converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter.
>   For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression **shall not refer to** (or for a pointer
>   type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject,
> - **a temporary object**,
> - a string literal,
> - the result of a typeid expression, or
> - a predefined *­*­func_­_­ variable.

`nullopt` is a constant of the type `nullopt_t`. Which is quite plainly not an `optional<int>`. As such, to bind that const reference we will need to materialize a temporary. But that explicitly makes the program ill-formed, as the text in bold indicates.

---

Mind you however, that you can have the parameter be a reference to a `nullopt_t`. Then you can pass `nullopt` for the argument. Though the utility of such a template is limited, I'd say.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. But is there any possibility to "tell" the function template `foo` that the `Dflt` is not present using `optional`? Or should I work here with pointers?

Comment: @bmk - If the template expects a reference, you can't avoid naming an object. A pointer parameter would allow you to specify `nullptr` for the argument, yes.

Comment: @bmk - You can also add an overload that accepts a `nullopt_t` reference, like in my note. But if you need it to do the exact same thing, it may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Non-type template parameters are very limited in what they can be.  Basically integers/enums or pointers/pointer-to-members/references.

[Story Teller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller)'s answer explains *why*.  The fix is to create a named constant that is the correct type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>

std::experimental::optional<int> dflt(42);
std::experimental::optional<int> nothing(nullopt);

template<const std::experimental::optional<int>& Dflt>
void foo() {
    if (Dflt) {
        std::cout << "default is set" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "default is not set" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
        foo<dflt>();    // <-- OK
        foo<nothing>(); // <-- Should be fine.
}
```

Comment: Ah... I'm not sure the second option is strictly valid. Maybe I'm reading [temp.param]/4 wrong? https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4

Comment: second option doesn't work (at least not with my g++ 5). That was actually my first implementation. The compiler says: `‘class std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<int>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter`

Comment: And the first option would work for the simple example in my question, but what I was actually really trying to do, was something like this: `template<typename T, std::experimental::optional<T>& Dflt> void foo() {}`. Then I would have to have templatize `nothing` for every `T` parameter? Hmm then it could actually work, but I don't know if it is a good idea though...

Comment: @bmk - You can define `nothing` as a varaible template. Not sure how well GCC 5.4 supports those however.

Comment: Why not introduce `template<typename T> constexpr optional<T> typed_nullopt = nullopt;` (namespace omitted)?

Comment: @StoryTeller Well I suppose you *might* be, but it's actually one of the clearer pieces of the standard.  The alternative is that I am talking rubbish - which is always an option that should be given careful consideration.

Comment: @MartinBonner I godbolted the second example, and apparently no current compiler accepts it. StoryTeller's reading seems correct, too. Arguably, it *should* be legal to use a class type in a manner compatible with `constexpr` (i.e. using a `constexpr` c'tor and trivial d'tor), but that's not what the standard says right now.

Comment: @ArneVogel : I was being ironic.  *Of course* StoryTeller is right - which is why I removed the example.